# Select highest version value from JSON array

Tags: bash, shell, jq

I have an JSON result and i need to search for a specific value and get from the array.

For example here is my JSON and I need to search for a version `1.15` having the higher patch version inside the `validNodeVersions` array. So here I wanted to retrieve the value `1.15.12-gke.20` and that is the highest 1.15 versions for the array list. Can somebody please help on this?

Basically I am looking always to pick the highest patch release for any of the version. for `1.15` it is `1.15.12-gke.20`.

`gcloud container get-server-config --format json`

```json
{
  "channels": [
    {
      "channel": "REGULAR",
      "defaultVersion": "1.17.9-gke.1504",
      "validVersions": [
        "1.17.9-gke.6300",
        "1.17.9-gke.1504"
      ]
    },
    {
      "channel": "STABLE",
      "defaultVersion": "1.16.13-gke.401",
      "validVersions": [
        "1.16.13-gke.401",
        "1.15.12-gke.20"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "defaultClusterVersion": "1.16.13-gke.401",
  "defaultImageType": "COS",
  "validImageTypes": [
    "UBUNTU",
    "UBUNTU_CONTAINERD"
  ],
  "validMasterVersions": [
    "1.17.12-gke.500",
    "1.14.10-gke.50"
  ],
  "validNodeVersions": [
    "1.17.12-gke.500",
    "1.16.8-gke.12",
    "1.15.12-gke.20",
    "1.15.12-gke.17",
    "1.15.12-gke.16",
    "1.15.12-gke.13",
    "1.15.12-gke.9",
    "1.15.12-gke.6",
    "1.15.12-gke.3",
    "1.15.12-gke.2",
    "1.15.11-gke.17",
    "1.15.11-gke.15",
    "1.15.11-gke.13",
    "1.15.11-gke.12",
    "1.15.11-gke.11",
    "1.15.11-gke.9",
    "1.15.11-gke.5",
    "1.15.11-gke.3",
    "1.15.11-gke.1",
    "1.15.9-gke.26",
    "1.15.8-gke.3",
    "1.15.7-gke.23",
    "1.15.4-gke.22",
    "1.14.10-gke.0",
    "1.14.9-gke.0"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiast programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: Add your JSON file and your desired output to your question.

Comment: yes added the entire output  and mentioned the value i wanted to retrieve

Comment: thanks for the update. yes i am looking  for the highest version.  Example ```1.15.12-gke.20```  is the highest version for ```1.15```. I will  only a major and minor version(1.15) as input  and now i need to check and pick the highest patch version from the ```validNodeVersions``` array.

Comment: Please remember to minify your example, I did it for you. I removed half of the lines, also remember to validate your json before posting, I also fixed that. Also I removed the `jquery` (and the `linux`) tag, if you really want this tag, feel free to add them. I see that you want to do this task with `jq` and maybe little shell help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is more tricky to match the regex, sort or anything inside `jq`. GNU `sort` command has a nice parameter, `-V` that stands for version sorting, so here is a simple way to do this, also without any awk or sort splitting to fields or similar.

```sh
jq -r '.validNodeVersions[]' file.json | grep "^1\.15" | sort -V | tail -1
1.15.12-gke.20
```

`jq` is doing a simple selection of values here, `grep` filters these values by version and after sorting by version we get the highest.

Comment: similarly i can select the 1.15 full version from the above ```STABLE```  channel list also, right?                                                                                                                        ```gcloud container get-server-config --format json | jq -r '.channels[2]'.validVersions[] | grep "^1.15" | sort -V | tail -1```

Comment: Yes, you have to modify only the jq selector according to your JSON, just follow the path.

Comment: I'd suggest you to quote a dot char `.` in grep regex as well, i.e.: `grep "^1\.15"`, otherwise it's prone to matching strings like "1-15...", "1215...", "1a15" and similar.

Comment: @Dmitry right! matching characters that could be a valid version number, for example version `1015.<subversions following>` (e.g. for ubuntu this version could exist in a few months). Updated answer, thanks.